# Can I used Georgian permits to travel to Schengen country

Tags: schengen, georgia-country, visa-free-entry

Am applying for Georgian permit in Tbilisi can I used my permits to travel to Schengen countries?

Comment: Well, given that Gerogian citzens can't travel to the shegan area without a visa, looks doubtful.

Comment: What do you mean by a "Georgian permit"? A visa?

Answer (score 2):

No, there is no scenario in which some sort of Georgian permit or visa opens any special access to the Schengen area. It is true that Georgia grants visa-free access to Schengen visa holders, but it only goes one way, Schengen countries do not recognize Georgian visas.